# Colors not setting in the list

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have made a customize list in which i have to give different colors to different list items.I tried doing it but the text color is always black.I don't know why this is happening;

Code-

```
private Context context;
private List<CommonModel> commonList = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String from;
private int[] languageColours = {R.color.green, R.color.pink, R.color.grey, R.color.chetna_red};

public CommonAdapter(Context context, List<CommonModel> commonList, String from) {
    this.context = context;
    this.commonList = commonList;
    this.from = from;
    inflater = inflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_custom_list_item, parent, false);
        holder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_common_content);
        holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_common_image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.ivImage.setImageResource(commonList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.tvContent.setText(commonList.get(position).getContent());
    holder.tvContent.setTextColor(languageColours[position]);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvContent;
    ImageView ivImage;
}
```

I had checked that the position which i am getting is correct then to the color is not changing.

Comment: Have you defined your colors in your colors.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `languageColours[position]` use `context.getResource.getColor(languageColours[position]);`

Comment: If you do a print out, `R.color.green` and `context.getResources.getColor(R.color.green)` are different values. This is why you aren't the colour you want.

Comment: @Terence when you use 'R.color.green' its mean you are creating identifier for particular color and when you use getResource.getColor(R.color.green ) you are getting color from resource using identifier.

Comment: so both are the same?

Comment: No they are different it's a comman mistake while using color https://benoit808.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/setting-color-from-resource-on-android/

Comment: Yes, my original comment was for OP's benefit to understand why he should have done what your answer stated :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
holder.tvContent.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
```